# No payment Method available on checkout screen

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Senario is :If customer is from Pakistan, then  theShipping method (Flat)  and the Payment method -Cash On Delivery will be shown . Now the issue is, I have done with all the settings as per the scenario but its still showing no Payment method available on checkout [image][![enter image description here][![enter image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKwrs.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKwrs.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljJK3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljJK3.png)
[image]

Comment: remember about minimum and maximum order amount

Comment: Yeah, just like Mr Konrad Siamro stated, remove the Minimum Order Total and Maximum Order Total and check if its working. Also make sure you configured this settings for your particular store view, and check for any Catalog / Cart Price Rules is set or not.